# Resultado incorrecto en división

Tags: c, revisión-de-código

Mi problema viene en el ciclo for, funciona la parte de do while. Pero cuando llega a for sea cual sea el número impar me da como resultado 1 y no se donde esta el problema.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h> 

int main(){

    int N, X;
    float OP, RES = 0;

        do {
        printf ("Introducir un numero impar y mayor que cero:\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &N); 
        }
       while((N <= 0) || (N%2==0));

    for (X=1; X<N; X+=2){

    OP = (1/X)*(-1);

    RES= RES - OP;

    }

    printf ("%f", RES); 

    return 0;
}
```

Ese es el ejercicio que estamos haciendo, y lo que debo poner que hasta el número impar que ponga hasta ahí lo realice. El lenguaje es en c y los comando son básicos la librería que estamos utilizando es studio.h.
Y pues solo esa y math.h podemos utilizar.

Si me podrían ayudar y que siempre se mantengan comando básicos.

Eso es lo que digo que solo uno me da de resultado y quiero que lo haga como la serie. Si me pueden decir que modificar le para que haga eso sería de gran ayuda. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Así es como me debe ir haciéndolo

Comment: Evitar poner imagenes para mostrar el codigo, te aconsejo que las saques y pegues el codigo directamente, ya que se hace muy larga tu pregunta debido a las imagenes.

Comment: Además de lo mencionado por favor redacta una introducción al problema en tu título, pues solo saludar puede generar que los demás usuarios pasen de largo tu pregunta, checa [ask]

Comment: BetaM ya lo hice

Comment: Deseas obtener solo el numero impar y termine el programa?

Comment: Amigo esta no es la forma de publicar la solución, si ya conseguiste como hacerlo y deseas compartirlo puedes hacerlo abajo en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 1):

El **problema principal** está en el cálculo `OP = (1/X)*(-1);`.

`X` es un entero, y al ejecutar `1/X` obtienes otro entero, de forma que cuando `X` es mayor que `1` la división da `0`.

- Si `X=1`: `1/X = 1` y `(1/X) * (-1) == -1`
- Si `X=3`: `1/X = 0` y `(1/X) * (-1) == 0`

Aunque luego asignes el resultado a una variable `float`, los decimales ya se han perdido.

Para mantener el resultado correcto de la operación necesitas que, al menos, uno de los miembros sea `float`. Ya sea

- Indicando uno o los dos valores constantes como `float`: `OP = (1.0 / X) * (-1.0);`
- O casteando la variable `X`: `OP = (1 / (float)X) * (-1);`

Aparte de eso, hay algunos **problemas en la lógica del programa**. Si lo que quieres es iterar hasta `N` incluido, deberás cambiar la condición del `for`:

```
for (X=1; X<N; X+=2){
```

Por

```
for (X=1; X<=N; X+=2){
```

- En el primer caso:

  - `N=1` no entra en el bucle
  - `N=3` solo entra con `X=1`, pero no con `X=3`. Por lo que el resultado de la fórmula sería [image: \pi/4 = 1]
- En el segundo caso:

  - `N=1` resultaría [image: \pi/4 = 1]
  - `N=3` entraría hasta `X=3` resultando  [image: \pi/4 = 1 - 1/3]

Por otro lado, cada vez que calculas el operador `OP` lo multiplicas por `(-1)`, convirtiéndolo en negativo, para después restárselo al resultado `RES`. De forma que se le suma siempre el operador al resultado.

Según se desprende de la fórmula que has puesto, los operadores deben ir alternando, por lo que necesitarás implementar un mecanismo para alternar los signos.